# Contour in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, contour

How `Z` is calcutalted in

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import contour

contour([X, Y,] Z, [levels], **kwargs)
```

to draw a contour?

I know that `Z` means: *The height values over which the contour is drawn.*

But is it drawn by calculating a standard deviation or something like that?

An average between each point I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Z` represents a quantity dependent on both `X` and `Y` axes. If `X` and `Y` represent a plane, `Z` can be thought of as a surface, whose point height depends on the `X` and `Y` coordinates of that given point. The contour is a "top view" of that surface, a projection. An example are the contour lines which report the heights of the mountains (`Z`) as longitude (`X`) and latitude (`Y`) change.
The `contour` function of `matplotlib`, as you wrote it, plots the values expressed in the `Z` variable (two-dimensional `numpy.ndarray`, as `X` and `Y`) as they are, without further processing. The relationship between `Z` and `X` and `Y` is defined outside the plot function.
I report an example below which, perhaps it may be useful:

```
# IMPORT
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# INPUT
N = 100
x_min = 0
x_max = 10
y_min = 0
y_max = 10
z_min = 0
z_max = 50
z_step = 1
red = '#de7677'

# DEFINE MESH GRID
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, N)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, N)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# CALCULATE ZZ AS A FUNCTION OF XX AND YY, FOR ESAMPLE, THEIR SUM
ZZ = YY + XX

# PLOT THE CONTOUR
fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize = (10, 10))

cont = ax.contour(XX,
                  YY,
                  ZZ,
                  levels = np.arange(z_min, z_max + z_step, z_step),
                  colors = red)

# SET THE CONTOUR LABELS
pl.clabel(cont, fmt = '%d')

# SET THE X AND Y LABEL
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

pl.show()
```